# UisplitViewController issue in ios 7(crash)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisplitviewcontroller, ipad

I have to instantiate in one of the view controllers.

```
UISplitViewController *splitViewController =  [kStoryBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"splitController"];
UINavigationController *navigationController = [splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject];
splitViewController.delegate = (id)navigationController.topViewController;
splitViewController.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;

splitViewController.presentsWithGesture = NO;
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:navigationController.topViewController action:@selector(swipeDetected:)];
swipeRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft|UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;

[splitViewController.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeRecognizer];
CGRect frame = splitViewController.view.frame;
frame.origin.x = 0;
frame.size.height -=100;
frame.origin.y +=100;
splitViewController.view.frame = frame;
UINavigationController *masterNavigationController = [splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
     MasterViewController *masterVC = (MasterViewController*)[masterNavigationController topViewController];
masterVC.currentCategory = [categoriesArray objectAtIndex:sender.tag-1];



self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
[self.navigationController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:splitViewController] animated:YES];
```

My app crashes on this line.

```
   [self.navigationController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:splitViewController] animated:YES];
```

It is working fine for ios 5 and ios 6.
Crash occurs only in ios 7.

This is the error.

`[UINavigationController _setViewControllers:transition:animated:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-2903.2/UINavigationController.m:768
2013-10-21 18:51:37.009 TruAirSync[1723:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UISplitViewControllers are not allowed in a navigation controller!'`

Comment: I have the same problem. Does anyone know any workaround on this without making the UISplitViewController the root view controller?

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer.
Hope it will help others also.

We just need to use a view controller.

```
UIViewController *containerVC = [[UIViewController alloc]init];

[containerVC.view setFrame:splitViewController.view.frame]; 
[containerVC.view addSubview:splitViewController.view];
[containerVC addChildViewController:splitViewController];
[splitViewController didMoveToParentViewController:containerVC];
[self.navigationController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:containerVC] animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

Just create another UIViewController and add you splitviewcontroller's view to it's subview than you can use it in a UINavigationController.

```
YourContainerController *containerController = [YourContainerController new];
[containerController.view addSubview:splitViewController.view];
[self.navigationController setViewControllers:@[containerController] animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

The UISplitViewController should be the root view of your application window.  Not sure why this was working for you in iOS 5 and 6.  You can not push a UISplitViewController into a UINavigationController.

From Apple's [documentation:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/SplitViewControllers.html)

> A split view controller must always be the root of any interface you
>   create. In other words, you must always install the view from a
>   UISplitViewController object as the root view of your application’s
>   window.

Comment: I know that part.
But what I want to know is how can we use it using UInavigationController using setViewControllers property.

Comment: Not possible.  It must be the root view controller.  There are UISplitViewController replacements you might want to try.

Comment: Found the answer.  
We just need to use a view controller. 





 UIViewController *containerVC = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
    
    [containerVC.view setFrame:splitViewController.view.frame];

    [containerVC.view addSubview:splitViewController.view];
    [containerVC addChildViewController:splitViewController];
    [splitViewController didMoveToParentViewController:containerVC];

    [self.navigationController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:containerVC] animated:YES];